# Batch file to look for file from today and run another .bat otherwise run vbs and exit

Tags: date, batch-file, if-statement

I have a batch file I would like to search a folder for any xlsm file updated today.
If it finds an xlsm file from today, it then runs another bat file. If there is no updated file it should run a .vbs file (to send an email) and then exit.

Currently I have the following:

```
@echo off
set var=%date:~-10%
dir "*.xlsm"|find "%var%">nul&&CALL Update.bat||EXIT
```

I think I probably need to include some sort of IF/ELSE instead of the current method, but my skills are lacking..

**EDIT:**
The actual solution I've gone with, based on the answer from @Monacraft is:

```
@echo off
forfiles /p C:\ /m *.xlsm /d 0 /c "cmd /c call Update.bat"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 start FailEmail.vbs
```

Comment: Options - 
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=today_2k
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=todaynow_nt

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=yesterday_nt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using windows 7 you could do `forfiles`:

```
@echo off
set found=FALSE

forfiles /p "C:\...[path to folder]" /m *.xlsm /d +1 /c "cmd /c Echo Updating...&CALL Update.bat&set found=TRUE"

if /i %found%==False (
start email.vbs
) else (
Exit
)
```

And that should work fine

Mona

Comment: Thanks Mona, but it is running the .vbs instead of the .bat no matter when the .xlsm is updated.

Comment: Yea, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, I must not have explained very well!

If an xlsm from today is found, then it should run the update.bat
If there is no xlsm from today, it should just run the FailEmail.vbs and exit.

Comment: Type `forfiles /?` and you can customise it to do what you want.

Comment: I've changed it around a bit. Below is the output I'm getting.. Not sure how to get `found` set to `TRUE`.

`C:\>forfiles /p "C:\" /m *.txt /d +0 /c "cmd /c set found=TRUE"`
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'found=TRUE'.

Comment: ok, have changed to:
`set found=FALSE
forfiles /p C:\ /m *.txt /d 0 /c "cmd /c echo Updating...&set found=TRUE"`

But `set` still isn't working.. after I run `forfiles /p C:\ /m *.txt /d 0 /c "cmd /c echo Updating...&set found=TRUE"` I check what is set `set f` and still get `FALSE=FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
@echo off
forfiles /p C:\ /m *.xlsm /d 0 /c "cmd /c call Update.bat"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 start FailEmail.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work - some small changes here.

It will just `echo` the commands to the screen, for you to test.

One point to consider is that the DIR command will also match `*.xls` files in the short name.

```
@echo off
set "var=%date:~-10%"
dir "*.xlsm"|find "%var%">nul && (echo CALL Update.bat) || (echo start failemail.vbs)
pause
```

Comment: Have worked out a method with forfiles

`@echo off`<br/>
`forfiles /p C:\ /m *.xlsm /d 0 /c "cmd /c call Update.bat"`<br/>
`if ERRORLEVEL 1 start FailEmail.vbs`<br/>

This way, I get an error if there are no files updated today, so it doesn't run Update.bat 
That gives me an error, so I figured I'd use that to kick off the vbs.

Cheers :-)